# Using ngx-mask with angular 4, how can I set a mask for only a few characters

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I set a mask for only a few characters and leave the rest free?

For example, mask = '(099) .... Here I can type whatever I want including *, (,), -'

I tried to mask '(099) AAAAAAAAAA' but I can not type special characters at this point.

In this way the value typed could be as "(061) *-/asadfas df " or " (061) ---()asadas" no matter what would come after the value informed of the mask (099)

Answer (score 0):

Try mask like below

```
[dropSpecialCharacters]="true" mask="XXX/X0/0000"
```